# Delete an entry from array of objects on button click

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am given the following object, I need to delete a `destination_field` and then loop that new object inside HTML

```
var columnDropdownStatesJobDetails = {header: "Collection Status", field: "collection_status"}
          {header: "Hostname", field: "hostName"}
          {header: "Device Id", field: "deviceId"}
          {header: "Sensor data", field: "sensorData"}
          {header: "Destination", field: "destination_id"}
          {header: "Last Reported Time", field: "lastReportedTime"}
```

following is what I did

```
private setDestColChecked(tabSelected, oldVal, newVal) {
  debugger;
  this.newObj= this.columnDropdownStatesJobDetails;
  if (this.columnDropdownStatesJobDetails.length > 0) {
    this.newObj.filter(function(e) {
      if (tabSelected === 'destinationTab' && (e.field === 'destination_id') && (e.visible === oldVal)) {
        e.visible = newVal;
      } else { 
        // here is my attempt to delete this field
        if (e.field === 'destination_id') {
          delete e.field;
          // return e.field !== 'destination_id';
          // delete this.columnDropdownStatesJobDetails.destination_id;
        } 
      }
    });
    console.log(this.newObj);
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

```
<ng-container *ngFor='let col of columnDropdownStates'>
                        <label *ngIf='col' class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" id={{col.field}} [checked]="col.visible" name={{col.header}}
                                   (change)="onColumnCheckboxChange($event)"/>
                            <span class="checkbox__input"></span>
                            <span class="checkbox__label">{{col.header}}</span>
                        </label>
                    </ng-container>
```

Comment: Please add your HTML Snippet, then where is this function called? please add a proper description so the community can understand and help you.

Comment: Is `person2` an array?

Comment: @ParthRaval Just added the HTML code above..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit confused about what you are trying to do, but let me give it a try.
You are doing a filter here. So you just need to write your filter condition and that item will not be there is your output list:

```
var x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var y = x.filter(function(e){e > 3})
console.log(y) // y = [4]
```

But if you want to change something by iterating a `foreach` should work. Am not clear about the type of `columnDropdownStatesJobDetails`, if its a map you can just `delete columnDropdownStatesJobDetails['destination_id']`

Answer (score 0):

try this, just change it to forEach

```
this.newObj.forEach(function(e) {
        if (tabSelected === 'destinationTab' && (e.field === 'destination_id') && (e.visible === oldVal)) {
            e.visible = newVal;
        } else { 
            if (e.field === 'destination_id') {
               delete e.field;
            } 
        }

    });
    console.log(this.newObj)
```